# Are ContainerRequestFilter and ContainerResponseFilter thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, jax-rs, servlet-filters

I have below code, it works fine. My question is weather below code is thread safe or not. By reading of Servlet Filter and Container*Filter concepts, I am confused.

How to make this filter as thread safe ?

```
 @Provider
public class ResourceLoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter,   ContainerResponseFilter {

@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

@Context
private HttpServletRequest  servletRequest;

@Inject
private java.util.logging.Logger logger;

public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,  ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
    String stTime = (String) requestContext.getProperty("StartTime"); 
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"<== Leaving Resource Path: "+ requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"<== Leaving Resource Method: "+  resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"<== Leaving Resource class: "+ resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getCanonicalName());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"<== Leaving Session id: "+ servletRequest.getSession().getId());
    if (null == stTime || stTime.length() == 0) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"start-time not captured or cleared");
        stTime = "0";
    }
    long startTime = Long.parseLong(stTime);
    long executionTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Total execution time : "+executionTime+" nano seconds."  );

}

public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    requestContext.setProperty("StartTime", String.valueOf(System.nanoTime())); 
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"==> Entering Resource Path: "+ requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"==> Entering Resource Method: "+  resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getName());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"==> Entering Resource class: "+ resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getCanonicalName());
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"==> Entering Session id: "+ servletRequest.getSession().getId());

}

}
```

**EDIT**
Is it good to have `private volatile String stTime;` statement, So that stTime can be thread safe??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's already thread-safe. Both the `ResourceInfo` and the `HttpServletRequest` are proxies (using thread-locals), while the methods on [java.util.Logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) are thread-safe.

**See aslo:**

- [Jersey 2: filters and @Context injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33632538/2587435)
- [Request-scoped context field injections into RESTEasy singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30591733/2587435)

Comment: What if multiple responses access String stTime = (String) requestContext.getProperty("StartTime");  ??

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I am thinking, filter() in response is not thread safe and stTime is Overriding by another response/thread while first thread calculating execution time at the bottom.

Comment: Each request gets it's own ContainerRequest(Response)Context. So I am not following where you think this could possibly cause a problem